# Pausing issue in Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have created a workflow in SPD 2010 but have one issue
It is working as follows:

If 'comments' field is update it will send mail , if it is not updated it will check for 1 hour and send reminder mail to assignee.

If comment is not null , then send email
Else , Pause for 1 hour
If comment is null , send email

but when workflow start and comment field is not empty it will send mail and if comment field is empty it will pause for 1 hour.
The issue is if comment field is updated after pause start for 60 minutes , then pause should stop and mail need to send, but this is not happening. Every time it is pausing for full 60 minutes even comment field is updated in between and user have to wait for next 60 minutes. also for every workflow step after pause user have to wait which should not happen

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of your workflow logic?

Comment: oh, not able to post screenshot, may be some IE error.
I have solved the issue from my end.I have created another workflow and added pause for duration there and removed pause from 1st workflow.It is working now as required.Thanks :)